# Не создается связь один ко многим

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, миграция

Пытаюсь сделать модели с информацией о студентах и их расписанием
Добавил такие модели:

```
public class GroupInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public long GroupId { get; set; }

    public string? GroupName { get; set; }

    public string? Faculty { get; set; }

    public int? Course { get; set; }
}

public class GroupTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual GroupInfo Group { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Lesson>? Lessons { get; set; }

    public string? Hash { get; set; }
}

[Table("Lessons")]
public class Lesson
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public string Teacher { get; set; }

    public bool Notificated = false; // Уведомлено о занятии
}
```

И контекст бд:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<GroupTable> Timetable { get; set; }


    public DatabaseContext() : base()
    {
        //Database.EnsureDeleted(); // Не забыть удалить
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql(
            "server=localhost;user=user;password=123456789;database=timetable;",
            new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 26))
        );
    }
}
```

После добавления и сохранения, все данных добавляются в соответствующие таблицы в бд.
Но когда после перезапуска и пытаюсь получить данные на месте Group и Lessons получаю null

Почему так происходит и как это можно исправить?

Спасибо, оказалось нужно было просто подгрузить данные при помощи Include (https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.3.php)

Comment: [Я случайно создал две учётные записи, как их объединить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

Покажите как вы пытаетесь получить данные. Скорей всего вы их приводите к типу `List<GroupTable>` с помощью `.ToList()`?
https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.3.php - попробуйте ключевое слово `Include`